# How to use cdo climate command?

Tags: python, netcdf, cdo-climate

I want to subset a NetCDF file to extract a sub-period with cdo.

I run the following code in spyder

```
 from cdo import *
cdo = Cdo()

cdo.select('startdate=2003-01-01,end_date=2016-12-31', input='PATH/temperature.nc', output='output.nc')
```

I use spyder 3.10 and have the message :

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

when I run `cdo = Cdo()`

1. Maybe I should not run cdo in spyder?
2. Does the command is correct?

Comment: I do not follow the question. Spyder is for Python. CDO is run from the command line. How are you actually running CDO from Spyder?

Comment: That code should work. Though it could be a Python versioning issue. As an alternative you could use my package nctoolkit, which uses CDO as a backend. https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an issue with the `Cdo()` command after a homebrew upgrade on a mac, and uninstalling the cdo package and then reinstalling it solved it for me...

However, are you sure the error is in the `cdo=Cdo()` command? I notice you have an underscore in "end_date", is that a typo in your question or also in your code?

What about using `seldate` if you are only selecting dates?

```
from cdo import *
cdo = Cdo()
cdo.seldate('2003-01-01,2016-12-31', input='PATH/temperature.nc', output='output.nc')
```

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced a very similar problem, in my case problem is about the Windows as it is not possible to use CDO. Right now CDO is not supported in Windows system and the binary is not available in the windows conda repository.
Possible ways to overcome this obstacle is WSL, which emulates Unix in your Windows system. Then CDO should be downloaded for Unix. More detailed explanation is in CDO user guide -> 1.1 Installation.
Also the link of website: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-30001.1